# Check failed: 1 == NumElements() (1 vs. 2)Must have a one element tensor

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I want to predict by using tensorflow C++ API
But, an error occurred:

> Check failed: 1 == NumElements() (1 vs. 2)Must have a one element tensor

It's code for preparing inputs:

```cpp
tensorflow::Tensor loadImage(tensorflow::string fname){
    tensorflow::int32 width = 224;
    tensorflow::int32 height = 224;
    tensorflow::int32 nData = 1;
    tensorflow::int32 nVec = width*height;
    tensorflow::int32 channels = 3;
    auto tensor = tensorflow::Tensor(tensorflow::DT_FLOAT, tensorflow::TensorShape({1, height, width, channels}));
    auto mat = tensor.tensor<float, 4>();
    std::ifstream fin(fname, std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary);
    assert(!fin.fail());
    boost::iostreams::filtering_istream s;
    s.push(fin);
    char c;
    for(int i=0;i<nData;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<channels;j++){
            for(int h=0;h<height;h++){
                for(int w=0;w<width;w++){
                    s.get(c);
                    mat(i, j, h, w) = static_cast<float>(static_cast<uint8_t>(c)) / 255.0;
                }
            }
        }
    }std::cout << "Image Loaded" << std::endl;
    return tensor;
}
```

After executing this code, I got the error:

```cpp
status = session->Run(inputs, {"output_node0"}, {}, &outputs);
auto output_c = outputs[0].scalar<float>(); // an error occurred
```

I found similar question here.
According to [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42639413/check-failed-1-numelements-1-vs-1792must-have-a-one-element-tensor-in-t), it looks like I can solve by changing following code.

from

```cpp
auto output_c = outputs[0].scalar<float>();
```

to

```cpp
auto output_c = outputs[0].flat<float>();
```

But, I got build error.
For more information...

```cpp
error: static assertion failed: YOU_MADE_A_PROGRAMMING_MISTAKE
 #define EIGEN_STATIC_ASSERT(X,MSG) static_assert(X,#MSG);/tmp/tensorflow/include/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/TensorMap.h:224:7: note: in expansion of macro 'EIGEN_STATIC_ASSERT'
       EIGEN_STATIC_ASSERT(NumIndices == 0, YOU_MADE_A_PROGRAMMING_MISTAKE)
```

What is the reason for error?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error *and the shortest code necessary to reproduce* **it in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. -- Your question is mainly lacking in the "reproducability / completeness" department. Have you *tried* isolating the problem in a smaller piece of example code?

Answer (score 1):

> What is the reason for error?

Which one? You got multiple ones. And both cannot be answered when just showing a few unrelated lines of code.

You `loadImage` looks ok. But the session-run call looks strange. It should be

```
std::vector<tensorflow::Tensor> outputs;
tensorflow::ClientSession session(root);
TF_CHECK_OK(session.Run({some_operation}, &outputs));
float *result_float_data = outputs[0].flat<float>().data();
```

But these depend on the actual graph you are using.

Anyway, your implementation is a little bit cumbersome. I guess you just want to feed an image into a graph. There are two much simpler solutions to read an image in C++ and TensorFlow.

The pure TensorFlow version is just

```
tensorflow::Scope root = tensorflow::Scope::NewRootScope();

std::string fn = "Grace_Hopper.png";

auto net1 = tensorflow::ops::ReadFile(root, fn);
auto net2 = tensorflow::ops::DecodePng(root, net1);
auto net3 = tensorflow::ops::Cast(root, net2, tensorflow::DT_FLOAT);
auto net4 = tensorflow::ops::ExpandDims(root, net3, 0);
// do something here
auto net5 = tensorflow::ops::ResizeBilinear(root, net4, tensorflow::ops::Const(root, {2 * 606, 2 * 517}));
auto net6 = tensorflow::ops::Reshape(root, net5, tensorflow::ops::Const(root, {2 * 606, 2 * 517, 3}));
// convert back
auto net7 = tensorflow::ops::Cast(root, net6, tensorflow::DT_UINT8);
auto net8 = tensorflow::ops::EncodeJpeg(root, net7);

std::vector<tensorflow::Tensor> outputs;
tensorflow::ClientSession session(root);

// Run and fetch v
TF_CHECK_OK(session.Run({net8}, &outputs));
std::ofstream("output.jpg", std::ios::binary) << outputs[0].scalar<std::string>()();
```

And the TensorFlow+OpenCV version has a [few more lines](https://github.com/PatWie/tensorflow-cmake/blob/master/examples/resize/opencv_version.cc).